# Custom prefix string is not evaluated by localstack firehose with s3 destination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose, localstack

I'm trying to test a firehose delivery-stream to s3 creation with custom prefix, using localstack
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/s3-prefixes.html

but it seems that the format string I send as Prefix parameter is not evaluated, but rather taken as is and placed as prefix.
This is the aws cli command I'm using to create the delivery-stream

```
aws --endpoint-url $EP_URL firehose create-delivery-stream \
    --delivery-stream-name $DELIVERY_STREAM_NAME \
    --region $TEST_REGION \
    --s3-destination-configuration "RoleARN=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Test-Role,BucketARN=$DEST_BUCKET, \
BufferingHints={SizeInMBs=1,IntervalInSeconds=60},\
Prefix=\"myprefix/year=!{timestamp:yyyy}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:HH}/\""
```

and this is the resulting object in s3 after writing to the stream:

```
aws --endpoint-url $EP_URL s3 ls --recursive $DEST_BUCKET | tail -n 20

2022-11-23 17:11:10          5 myprefix/year=!{timestamp:yyyy}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:HH}/2022/11/23/15/mystream-2022-11-23-15-11-10-dd405ee0-0f74-4a16-9e24-df936935b782
```

Any ideas anyone? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know for sure but it seems that the prefix is concidered a string as is. Do you need the 'myprefix/' at the start of the prefix? And I believe the prefix needs to start with a forward slash such that: `/myprefix/year/...'. Try that out.

Comment: I don't need it, its just an example, the problem is that the expression year=!{timestamp:yyyy} should have been evaluated to 'year=2022' and that didn't happen. But it actually seems to be a known problem, although not by many:
https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/4417